# Building string from list of list of strings

Tags: kotlin

I rather have this ugly way of building a string from a list as:

```
val input = listOf("[A,B]", "[C,D]")

val builder = StringBuilder()
builder.append("Serialized('IDs((")
for (pt in input) {
 builder.append(pt[0] + " " + pt[1])
 builder.append(", ")  
}
builder.append("))')")
```

The problem is that it adds a comma after the last element and if I want to avoid that I need to add another if check in the loop for the last element.

I wonder if there is a more concise way of doing this in kotlin?

**EDIT**

End result should be something like:

```
Serialized('IDs((A B,C D))')
```

Comment: How should the end result look?

Comment: Added what the end result shoudl look like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin you can use [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) for this kind of use case (it deals with inserting the separator only *between* elements).

It is very versatile because it allows to specify a transform function for each element (in addition to the more classic `separator`, `prefix`, `postfix`). This makes it equivalent to mapping all elements to strings and then joining them together, but in one single call.

If `input` really is a `List<List<String>>` like you mention in the title and you assume in your loop, you can use:

```kotlin
input.joinToString(
    prefix = "Serialized('IDs((",
    postfix = "))')",
    separator = ", ",
) { (x, y) -> "$x $y" }
```

Note that the syntax with `(x, y)` is a destructuring syntax that automatically gets the first and second element of the lists inside your list (parentheses are important).

If your input is in fact a `List<String>` as in `listOf("[A,B]", "[C,D]")` that you wrote at the top of your code, you can instead use:

```kotlin
input.joinToString(
    prefix = "Serialized('IDs((",
    postfix = "))')",
    separator = ", ",
) { it.removeSurrounding("[", "]").replace(",", " ") }
```

Comment: Does this even compile? I have tried on Kotlin 1.6.10, this transformer has mismatching components.

Comment: This code would work if the input was a List of Lists, like: _listOf(listOf("A","B"), listOf("C","D"))_, but it does not compile with the OPs input string.

Comment: The OP was mentioning list of lists in the title, and the body of the OP's loop was suggesting the same, so I didn't pay attention to the input line. This works for a `List<List<String>>`. I added an alternative for the actual OP's input line

Comment: Aah.. right, missed the list of list part.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin provides an extension function `[joinToString][1]` (in `Iterable`) for this type of purpose.

```
input.joinToString(",", "Serialized('IDs((", "))')")
```

This will correctly add the separator.

Comment: mmh this doesn't transform the elements like the OP is doing, apart from that, I guess it's just my answer

Comment: Has OP mentioned what exact format is looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
val input = listOf("[A,B]", "[C,D]")

val result =
  "Serialized('IDs((" +
  input.joinToString(",") {  it.removeSurrounding("[", "]").replace(",", " ") } +
  "))')"

println(result)   // Output:   Serialized('IDs((A B,C D))')
```